# Cannot find the child_model (NameError)

Tags: ruby, sinatra, datamapper

I am unable to determine why I am getting a name error here. I'm new to DataMapper, but trying to associations down. Any help is appreciated.

User:

```
class User
  include DataMapper::Resource

  property :id,            Serial, :key => true
  property :first_name,    String
  property :last_name,     String
  property :company,       String
  property :city,          String
  property :country,       String
  property :mobile_number, Integer
  property :email_address, String
  property :shahash,       String
  property :isRegistered,  Boolean

  belongs_to :event, :required => true
end

DataMapper.auto_upgrade!
```

Event:

```
class Event
  include DataMapper::Resource

  property :id,          Serial, :key => true
  property :name,        String
  property :occuring,    DateTime

  has n, :user
end

DataMapper.auto_upgrade!
```

Comment: You should use `has n, :users`, plural form.

Comment: Still having issues when using `has n, :users` and `belongs_to :event`
Something else I'm missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the problem is you're calling `DataMapper.auto_upgrade!` after each model definition.  When you call it after just defining one model, there's no child model there.  Instead, you should define and/or require all your models and then do:

```
DataMapper.finalize      # set up all relationships properly
                         # and do a basic model sanity check
DataMapper.auto_upgrade! # create database table if it doesn't exist
```

Comment: I have my models broken out into separate files under /models.  Should I just call `DataMapper.finalize / DataMapper.auto_upgrade!` after I require all of my models?

(Sorry. Still getting used to ORMs & Ruby)

Comment: Yes, call them after you've required all of your models.

Comment: Looks like that was it =] Thanks nameless.

Comment: This helped me too, thank you!

A note for al3xnull -- I was also using a /models directory, and loading them from an init script. Since my require statement was a loop over sorted files, I added one called "zz_Loader" that handled finalizing DataMapper. It may help you.

Answer (score 0):

Add an init file in your models directory and move all of your your DataMapper.finalize statements to it (i.e. remove the finalize statement from your individual model files)

app/models/init.rb

```
require_relative 'file_name'
require_relative 'another_model_file_name'

DataMapper.finalize
```

Then in your application file require the init file

```
require_relative 'models/init'
```